# How do you get TERM=screen-256color on CentOS 5.7?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, term

CentOS 6.0 comes with the ability to set its TERM to `screen-256color`. It doesn't work in CentOS 5.7, though.

How can you get CentOS 5.7 to support `screen-256color`?

Answer (score 9):

If you have a CentOS 6 box handy, you should be able to get the source of the terminfo file for screen-256color and then compile it on the CentOS 5 box.

Take a look at:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html

I haven't tried it, but something like this:

On the CentOS 6: `infocmp screen-256color > /tmp/screen-256color.terminfo`, then get the output file to the CentOS 5 box.  On the CentOS 5 box, `tic screen-256color.terminfo`.  From the man page, as root, that should place the compiled terminfo file into /usr/share/terminfo.

Of course, read documentation and man pages, etc.

Comment: Just an FYI: On one of my boxes, the permissions got messed up for `/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color`; it was only readable by root. A simple `chmod a+r /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color` fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh, also: This works on any terminfo based unix system. Though the directory it writes to may be different.

Comment: You can do it all in one command if you have SSH access between the two. On the CentOS 5 machine, run `tic <(ssh CENTOS6MACHINE infocmp screen-256color)`, where `CENTOS6MACHINE` is the hostname of your CentOS 6 machine. This will place it in the system-wide database if run as root, but if run as a normal user will put it in the right place in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is `xterm-256color` available? I've not used CentOS much, but the xterm one has been around for a while.

Comment: It is available, but it doesn't do what I need it to do. htop crashes while using xterm-256color inside of tmux.